# How to implement fuzzy field-centric (cross_fields) query on fields with multiple analysers?

Tags: elasticsearch

Mapping:

```
{
  "articles" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "data" : {
        "properties" : {
          "author" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "standard"
          },
          "content" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "english"
          },
          "tags" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "english"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example data:

```
{
    "author": "John Smith",
    "title": "Hello world",
    "content": "This is some example article",
    "tags": ["programming", "life"]
}
```

So as you see I have mapping with different analysers on different fields. Now I want to search across those fields in a following way:

- only documents matching **all** search keywords are returned (like *multi_match* with *cross_fields* as a *type* and *and* as *operator*)
- query should be fuzzy so it can tolerate some typos
- different fields should have different boost values (e.g. title more important than content)

For example following query should match above document:

```
programing worlds john examlpe
```

How can I do it? According to [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields) fuzziness won't work with cross_fields nor fields with different analysers.
One way of doing it would be implementing custom _all fields and coping all values there using copy_to but with this approach I can't assign different weights nor use different analysers.